# Queue Problem while modeling a shortest path algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, queue, vertex

I have a queue problem. Modeling a graph, I'm doing a shortest path algorithm in C++.

In my `while (!q.empty())` the front `vertex*` gets changed when I return to this statement.

Can you figure out why?

```
int MyMatrix::searchBreadth(MyVertex* from,MyVertex* to)
{
queue<MyVertex*> q;  
path=INFINITY;

from->visit();  
from->setDistance(0);  
q.push(from);  

//here q.front()'s attributes get changed when returning from the for-loop  
while(!q.empty())
{  
    MyVertex* v=q.front();  
    q.pop();  
    int k=v->getDistance();  
    vector<MyVertex> nb=getNeighbours(*v);  
    for(int i=0;i<nb.size();i++)  
    {  
        if(nb[i].getDistance()==INFINITY)
        {  
            nb[i].setDistance(k+1);  
            q.push(&nb[i]);  
        }

        if((nb[i].getName().compare(to->getName())==0)
           && !nb[i].isVisited())
        {
            //path found  
            int j=nb[i].getDistance();  
            if(j<path) path=j;  
        }  

        nb[i].visit();  
     }  
}  
return path;  

}
```

here comes getNeighbours()

```
vector<MyVertex> MyMatrix::getNeighbours(MyVertex &v)
{  
    int index=0;  
    for(int l=0; l<stations.size(); l++ )
    {  
        if(stations[l].getName().compare(v.getName())==0)index=l;  
    }

    vector<MyVertex> out;  
    for(int k=0;k<matrixSize;k++)
    {  
        if(matrix[index][k].getName().compare("null")!=0)
        {  
            out.push_back(matrix[index][k].getTo());  
        }  
    }  

    return out;
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm not 100% sure if I understand your problem. `q.front()` should change at each iteration. Unless you mean `v` changes during the `for` loop.

Comment: @sixlettervariables OP means *the attributes* of `q.front()` are changing, not `q.front()` itself.

Comment: @Howard: thanks, I've updated my answer to address the reason.

Comment: thanks already, i added getNeighbours()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is subtle, but related to `q.push(&nb[i])`. What you're doing is adding a pointer to a location in a vector, which is not conceptually the same as adding a pointer to a `MyVertex` object. The vector of neighbors contains the `MyVertex` objects "by value" (if that helps in your understanding of the problem).

A look at `nb` in memory may help:

```
        0         1                   I
nb [MyVertex0|MyVertex1|   ...   |MyVertexI]
             +---------+
                  | (Notice it is NOT pointing to MyVertex1!)
&nb[1]------------+
```

When you push `&nb[1]` you're pushing the address `nb + (1 * sizeof(MyVertex))`. `nb` is declared on the stack, so that address is going to be somewhere on the stack.

So when your `for`-loop comes back around, `nb` gets refreshed (so to speak) and new data is added. However, your queue `q` contains addresses into `nb` that are no longer valid!

Simply put: *your queue is referencing a LOCATION in the vector, not the DATA in the vector*.

<strike>If you want to keep your method as-is, this means `getNeighbors` needs to change to return a vector of `MyVertex*`.</strike>

---

You should simply edit `BreadthFirstSearch` to take two `MyVertex&`, rather than pointers. You would then change `q` to be a `queue<MyVertex>`, `v` to `MyVertex`, and finally you should change `q.push(&nb[i])` to just `q.push(nb[i])`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help! I changed scope of nb to method-wide and added a clear() before the next call of getNeighbours()  Now the address is not longer manipultaed! Great Help!